# VS Code C++/Cmake project, debugging info and breakpoints not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, lldb

I have a simple hello world code written in c++ in a porject. I have configured the CMake file as the following:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(test_project VERSION 1.0
                  DESCRIPTION "testing cmake"
                  LANGUAGES CXX)


add_library(announcable STATIC Libs/announcable.cpp Libs/announcable.h)
add_library(announcer STATIC Libs/announcer.cpp Libs/announcer.h)
target_include_directories(announcable PUBLIC include)
target_include_directories(announcer PUBLIC include)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC announcable)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC announcer)`
```

this is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            // Resolved by CMake Tools:
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            
            "environment": [
                {
                    // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
                    // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "$PATH:${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "OTHER_VALUE",
                    "value": "Something something"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the program runs fine. It takes my input and quits. However, the program doesn't show any information and doesn't stop at my breakpoints.

this is the main.cpp file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Libs/announcer.h"
#include "Libs/announcable.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "I'm a bunny girl\n";

    Announcable announcbl("merrrowwww");
    Announcer announcr(&announcbl);

    announcr.announce();

    std::string test;
    std::cin >> test;

    return 0;
}
```

the announcable and announcer classes are just to test linking and only print something.

I'm running on MacOS on an M1 Mac Air

I was hoping to see the usual info on my variables and call stack and I was expecting the program to stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: Build without optimization and enable debug symbols. Then try the debugger again.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it sadly did not help. the cmake is already set to debug which should do this, but i also tried compiling it with -O0 by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get my debugger working and fix a memory leak problem that I had with my code after extensively reading the documentation

this is simply my configuration, you should change the relevant portions to match your system and needs.

firstly I created the c_cpp_properties.json

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4 
}
```

this is my launch.json file, change the "program" argument to your executable:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Bunget",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            
        }
    ]
  }
```

I also added this to my settings.json

```
{
    "cmake.debugConfig": {
        "type": "lldb"
    },
```

I hope that this answer may help someone in the future struggling with the same debugging freezing and or memory leak issues with the debugger.